# Pass compile flags to pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, options

In C I can do this:

```
gcc -DOPTION file.c
---
#ifdef OPTION
  ...code...
#endif
```

Is there a similar mechanism in LaTeX?

I am trying to write a manual for a product with lots of options.  I'd like to maintain one `*.tex` file, but recompile it with different compile flags to produce a document for a specific unit.

```
pdflatex \def\option{1} file.tex
---
To begin, press the \ifx\option1 green\else blue\fi button.
```

Reading `man pdflatex`, I don't see anything that stands out to me.  `TEXINPUTS` just defines search paths. `-src-specials` looks interesting because something is inserted into the file, but it doesn't apply to PDF mode.

---

I suppose one solution could be `\input{options}`, where `options.tex` is a symbolic link to a file defining options for a variant.  I don't know if this is the best idea.

---

I imagine this is not an unusual use case.  It's very possible that I'm thinking about this in the wrong way.

---

This is surprisingly hard to search.  A search for "latex flags" gives packages on how to render national flags.  A search for "latex options" give information on how to pass options to `\documentClass[option...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

passing via the command line is really not the tex way, you can do `pdflatex \def\option{1} \input{file.tex}` (not `pdflatex \def\option{1} file.tex`) but far more common is to have your document use `\documentclass{mymanual}` and have `mymanual.cls` do `\InputIfFileExists{mymanual.cfg}`  so you can put whatever settings you want in a cfg file (ltxdoc, hyperref, etc all have similar mechanisms)

That said, perhaps more covenient than defining macros on the commandline, you can use `kpsewhich` without shell-escape to access environment variables

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\input{"|kpsewhich  -expand-var $HOME"}

\end{document}
```

then

`pdflatex file` produces

[image]

HOME=wibble `pdflatex file` produces

[image]

Comment: Oh, I really like this!  Using an environment variable to select a file with the options set!  Must better than my `\input{options}` idea and using a symbolic link.

Comment: What do you call that leading pipe character in `|kpsewhich`?  I've never seen that syntax.  I'd like to read a bit about how that works.

Comment: @Stewart a leading pipe:-) see `texdoc web2c` section 5.5, ... "pdfTeX and luaTeX support reading (via \input and \openin) and writing (via \openout) from pipes if the first character is `|`"